# Printing IList Object values in AJAX call in C#

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using QPXExpress webservice API for the flight reservation and printing the JSON result through ajax call, but unable to print the IList object values in the function. Below is the code. I tried using a `foreach` loop, but it didn't work.

Tried to use debugger and post in alert function, but it didn't display the result.

**Model class**

**flightrecord.cs**

```
public class flightrecord
{

    private IList<CityData> city1;
    private IList<CityData> city2;
    private IList<AirportData> airport;
    private IList<TaxData> tax;

    public IList<CityData> City1
    {
        get
        {
            return city1;
        }

        set
        {
            city1 = value;
        }
    }

    public IList<CityData> City2
    {
        get
        {
            return city2;
        }

        set
        {
            city2 = value;
        }
    }

    public IList<AirportData> Airport
    {
        get
        {
            return airport;
        }

        set
        {
            airport = value;
        }
    }

    public IList<TaxData> Tax
    {
        get
        {
            return tax;
        }

        set
        {
            tax = value;
        }
    }

    public flightrecord()
    {

    }
    public flightrecord(IList<CityData> city1, IList<CityData> city2, IList<AirportData> airport, IList<TaxData> tax)
    {
        this.City1 = city1;
        this.City2 = city2;
        this.Airport = airport;
        this.Tax = tax;
    }
}
```

**Controller class**

```
public ActionResult flights()
{
    QPXExpressService service = new QPXExpressService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        ApiKey = "AIzaSyCMy1cF1_QPOVFXY5e6W6lD_o3ewv4AUNk",
        ApplicationName = "TripAdvisor",
    });

    TripsSearchRequest x = new TripsSearchRequest();
    x.Request = new TripOptionsRequest();
    x.Request.Passengers = new PassengerCounts { AdultCount = 2 };
    x.Request.Slice = new List<SliceInput>();

    x.Request.Slice.Add(new SliceInput()
    {
        Origin = "KHI",
        Destination = "LHR",
        Date = "2017-09-8"
    });
    x.Request.Solutions = 10;
    var result = service.Trips.Search(x).Execute();

    //List<flightrecord> record = new List<flightrecord>();
    //record.Add(new flightrecord(result.Trips.Data.City, result.Trips.Data.City, result.Trips.Data.Airport, result.Trips.Data.Tax));

    flightrecord record = new flightrecord(result.Trips.Data.City, result.Trips.Data.City, result.Trips.Data.Airport, result.Trips.Data.Tax);

    //   ViewBag.listflights = result;

    return Json(record, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#flights").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Hotel/flights",
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                //debugger;

                //alert(data.City1.Name);
                var s = '';
                for (var i in data.City1) {
                    s += data[i].City1.Name;
                }
                //var s = '';

                //s += 'city1: ' + data[i].City1.Name + '<br>city2: ' + data[i].City2.Name + '<br>airport :' + data[i].Airport.Name + '<br>tax: ' + data[i].Tax;
                //    $("#box").html('');
                $("#box1").html(s);


            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: In what way did it "not work"?  What is the actual value of `data` in your client-side callback function?  What are you trying to do with it?  It looks like you're expecting a single record, so what are you trying to use a *loop* for?

Comment: the returned result has 6 columns, i checked during debugging. That's why i got to use loop in ajax all.

Comment: It's very unusual to try to loop through the properties of a single object.  Usually the set of properties is static and known and one would simply reference them directly.  There's no array here, nothing to *loop over*.  You have a single object with some properties.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but i'm unable to find a way to print the data through ajax.

Comment: Well, what data are you trying to "print" and where are you trying to "print" it?  You can create strings from your properties, for example: `var x = 'City 1: ' + data.City1.Name + ', City 2: ' + data.City2.Name;`  And you can set strings to your page, for example: `$('#box').text(x);`  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well, i tried that before printing string from properties as you mentioned. But the returned result is undefined.

Comment: Which brings us back to the original question... What is `data`?  Something as simple as `console.log(data)` can show you the contents of that variable.  You can also place a breakpoint there in your browser's debugging tools and observe the value at runtime.  Maybe I misread and there *is* a collection in here somewhere?  The parent object is a single object, what are its properties?  I would expect `City1` to be, well, a `City`.  Is it instead a poorly-named collection of `City` instances?  Don't randomly try things, observe the actual values and define what you need to do with them.

Comment: City1 for instance, itself returning a list of 5 counts. and in each count there are properties of Code, Country, Etag, Kind and Name. Wiithin this City1, i'm trying to extract Name and display it on the page. If i just write data.City1 in ajax call, it returns with [Object object] and just directly using data.City1.Name returns undefined value.

Comment: Huh, it was just the small mistake that i was making. Thanks you @David, by the way do i need to iterate through each collection of list individually to print? or something else?